# How to perform sum aggregation on n number of documents after sorting records (descending) ? elastic

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, querydsl

{so, i want latest 30 document between 20/6 to 20/4 and perform the sum aggregation on field duration_seconds of those 30 latest doc. we had tried multiple aggregation on that like top_hits, terms for sorting but then we got the sum of all doc between 20/6 to 20/4}

````
  "size": 1,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "create_datetime": {
              "gte": "2022-04-20",
              "lte": "2022-06-20"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "create_datetime": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "aggs": {
    "videosession": {
      "sampler": {
        "shard_size":30
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sum_duration_seconds": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "duration_seconds"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}```
````

Comment: Can you show us what you have already tried instead of just saying what you want?

Comment: i have also tried terms aggregation for example: terms:{fields:"integer field", order:[{"integer_field":"desc"}], size:30} , actually i want the sum of top 30 records from last 60 days records and those top 30 are in descending order.